# TextView displays different text than received with getText

Tags: android, settext

I have a problem with setText(). Although there were many questions about this issue, no single answer solved my problem..

I have one city name saved with SharedPreferences. I get city successfully from SharedPreferences. I want to do the following textview.setText(city) [of course, firstly I determine the textview with findbyId-proper, existing id ]. This is done in onResume() method.
Than I use getText() and System.out.println(getText()) shows exactly the right, saved city. The UI shows the text which was defined at the XML layout of the activity.
I have no idea what to do and how is this even possible. I do not get any errors.
Please, help.

In onResume() method right after super.onResume(); :

```
        city=settings.getString("savedLocation", "null");
        textView.setText(city);
        System.out.println(city + " " textView.getText());
```

Comment: We might be able to assist you better if you provided us with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`textView.getText()` returns not text string, but object. You should use `textView().getText().toString()` to retrieve text from a text view

Comment: The same result came out.